# Xcode C++ Unit testing with global variable

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I've got a problem when unit testing my program. 
The problem is simple but i'm not sure why this is not working.

1 -> i build all my program 
2 -> i build my unitTest
3 -> the test is running.

All is ok when it is not about getting global data from the data segment. It seems as if the variable are not initialized / or simply found. So of course all my tests become wrong.

My question is: 
Is it totally wrong to build an executable, then running the test on it? Or should i must compile all my code + the unit test in the same time, and then running it? Or is it just a lack of SenTesting framework?

I forgot to mention that this is a C++ const string. Dunno if that change something.

*EDIT***

My assumption was wrong, but i still don't understand the magic beyond! Seems a C++ magic hoydi hoo?

```
char cstring[] = "***";
std::string cppString = "***";
NSString* nstring = @"***";

- (void)testSync{
    STAssertNotNil(nstring, nil); // fine
    STAssertNotNil((id)strlen(bbb), nil); // fine
    STAssertNotNil((id)cppString.size(), nil); // failed
}
```

*EDIT 2***

Actually this is normal that the C++ is not initialized at this part of the code. If i do a nm on my executable, it appears that my C and Obj-C global are put into the dataSegment. I thought my C++ string was in the same case, but it is actually put into the bss segment. That's means it's uninitialized. The fact is the C++ compiler do some magic beyond and the C++ string is initialized after the main() call and act like if it were into the dataSegment.

I didn't know that testSuit doesn't have main() call, so the C++ object are never initialized. There is some technique in order to call the .ctor before the testSuit. But i am too lazy too explain and it's some kind of topic. I have just replaced my C++ string with a simple char array, and it work perfectly since my value are now POD.

By the way there is no devil in global variable if they are just read-only. ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I can see a few faults here.

First of all, this code gives errors on my environment (Xcode 5) and for good reasons (with ARC enabled). I don't know how you got the thing to compile. The reason is that you are casting an integer (or long) to an object, and this will result in many errors, as it is normally an invalid operation. So, the real question is not why the third "assert" failed, but why the second one succeeded.

As far as the second part of your question is concerned, I have to admit that I do not completely understand your question, and you may have to explain it more thoroughly.

In general, unit testing is testing specific parts of your code. Therefore, you typically don't perform the tests on an actual final executable (this is not called unit testing, I believe), nor do you have to compile "all your c++ code + your unit tests at the same time".

Since you are using Xcode, I will give you some indications.

- Write your application (or at least a part of it), and find the aspects / functions / objects you want to perform unit tests on.
- In separate files, write unit tests that instantiate these objects and test their methods, call them and compare the inputs and outputs.
- You should have a second target in your application, that will compile only the unit test source code and the relevant main program code.
- Build this target, or press command-U and it will report successes and failures.

So, you need to separate your source code and isolate your classes / methods to make them testable like this. This needs a good architecture and design of the application on your part, and you may need to make some compromises in flexibility (that is up to you to decide). Oh, and I believe that in a testable code you should avoid global variables in general, for various reasons. Global variables are helpful sometimes, but they generally make unit testing really difficult, (and if misused may lead to spaghetti code, but this is a whole different story)

I hope I helped, even without fully understanding the second part of your post.

Comment: Hi csotiriou. I have finally found a kind of solution, i just forget to close the topic. Below i have posted the answer, in case someone fall into the same trap.